# Internet explorer re-sizing elements as page is updated

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer, data-binding

My problem is an Internet Explorer issue. I have an element, basically just a block, with the css:

```
md-card{
        min-width: 80%;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

And this element is full of data elements consisting of an icon and text.
Each one is either a file or folder, and clicking a folder just navigates to that folder's contents.

These elements are using data binding and are dynamically updated when you click a folder (so it removes the current contents and replaces the data with the opened folders new contents) and for some reason this causes a problem in IE

The `md-card` element despite having `min-width` set to 80% will *sometimes* squash down to like an inch big on the screen when a folder is opened. Sometimes this happens only for an instant, and it resizes, and sometimes it sticks. But resizing the page will cause it to resize back to the intentded width.

I was thinking it was some weird interaction between angularjs and IE but I'm wondering if this is an issue anyone has encountered or and ideas on why this is happening.

Edit: On further inspection it seems to involve the `min-width: 80%` attribute.
Changing it to `min-width: 600px`eliminates the problem.

Comment: I would have to write it from scratch, but if that's needed I can work on it.

Comment: Here's an example of this IE issue, it appears to be pretty common: https://jsfiddle.net/jLkurp3y/
Open in IE and compare to other browsers

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Internet Explorer is always bugging but I figured out the solution please add this line to md-card CSS sheet . As you mentioned that it is basically a block , consider this .

```
       md-card{
               display: block ;         /*Add this line*/
               min-width: 80%;
               background-color: #fff;
          }
```

Internet Explorer is  not as intelligent as chrome or Firefox , so the default is always display:inline ;
Therefore the layout problem occurs .